# Highcharts - column stacked Y axis

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to have columns with data series going in the Y axis instead of X axis? I would also need to specify the colour for each data and generate a legend for all of them

[image]

This fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vyamk5cg/
get close but unfortunately the legend doesn't reflect the colour of each value

```
name: "'15",
    data: [{
        y: 2,
      color: '#ff0000'
    }, {
        y: 3,
      color: '#00ff00'
    }, {
        y: 1,
      color: '#0000ff'
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define each point as an outstanding series and attach them to the common stack.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vnuo9m1/

```
  series: [{
    name: '`15',
    stack: '15',
    color: '#ff0000',
    data: [{
      y: 2,
    }]
  }, {
    name: '`15',
    stack: '15',
    color: '#990000',
    data: [{
      y: 1,
    }]
  }, {
    name: '`15',
    stack: '15',
    color: '#550000',
    data: [{
      y: 3,
    }]
  }, {
    name: '`16',
    stack: '16',
    color: '#00ff00',
    data: [{
      y: 2,
    }]
  }, {
    name: '`16',
    stack: '16',
    color: '#009900',
    data: [{
      y: 1,
    }]
  }, {
    name: '`16',
    stack: '16',
    color: '#005500',
    data: [{
      y: 3,
    }]
  }]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.stack

Comment: last question @SebastianWędzel , how can I handle the categories? at the moment they are under one category on the X axis...thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b20duhns/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping

Comment: wow! thanks so much! still wrapping my head around highcharts and this is a big help